# Release apk build failed

Tags: flutter, dart, release-apk

## I am trying to build release apk of a project, but getting following errors:

### debugging APK is running fine

```
Multiple build operations failed.
    Could not create task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
    Could not create task ':google_maps_flutter_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
    Could not create task ':image_picker_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
    Could not create task ':shared_preferences_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
    Could not create task ':url_launcher_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
Could not create task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
this and base files have different roots: E:\tracking App project\Dmft_bokaro\build\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle and C:\Users\Win11\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.15\android.
```

## I have used the following versions of dependencies:

```
`dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  shared_preferences: ^2.1.2
  flutter_map: ^0.14.0
  latlong2: ^0.8.2
  http: ^0.13.4
  geolocator: ^7.1.1
  intl: ^0.17.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.7
  flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle: ^2.0.15
  permission_handler: ^10.3.0
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.3.1
  maps_launcher: ^2.2.0
  dio: ^5.2.1+1
  modal_progress_hud_nsn: ^0.4.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.9
  table_calendar: ^3.0.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.3.1
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1`
```

## My app/build.gradle version is :

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    namespace "com.example.dmft_bokaro"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.dmft_bokaro"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

## My android/build.gradle version is :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`I have tried to flutter clean, flutter pub get, flutter upgrade... my debugging apk is running fine`

Answer (score 1):

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

signingConfig signingConfigs.release please change debug to release mode like this

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code on the following path `android/app/build.gradle`

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following algorithm helped me solve the problem:

**1.** Use the menu "Tools > Flutter > Flutter Clean" or enter the command "`flutter clran`" in the terminal.

**2.** Enter the command into the terminal: "`flutter pub cache repair`"

**3. Use the menu: “File > Invalidate Caches...”: check all the boxes, there are three of them. Next > Click “Invalidate and restart”, and then wait for Android Studio to launch.**
open the “Android” module and rejoice at the message “Gradle Sync Finished”.

I also want to point out that the problem seems to be with the Gradle version. Try downgrading via the menu: Tools > AGP Upgrade Assistant.

Good luck!